# This string has a value I need to extract and its usually at the end of the string

Tags: sql-server

Can someone help me please?
Eg.

1 x E10,Day rate per hour,1

1 x E10

1 x E2A,"As E2 but with wireless roomstat, also assumes power available within 2m (this code only)",2.5

I got thousands of rows like the sample above and would like to extract the last figures before the comma from the right

How can I extract that figures from the string please using SQL script?

From the three samples above, I would please like to see something like this:

1

this should be blank or 0 since the expected figure is not there in this case

2.5

I think I need to use a substring and charindex but cannot get it working.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: what kind of errors are you getting? where is the code?

Comment: I'm not sure how to apply it in this case. I have only ever used it to do something like this:       SUBSTRING(PatientsName,CHARINDEX(' ',PatientsName + ' ')+1,LEN(PatientsName)) as test. Thank you

Comment: Please read the instructions on the [sql server tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql-server/info) on how to write a good SQL question and [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using CHARINDEX and RIGHT to extract the values

```
IIF(CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(column)) > 0, RIGHT(column, CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(column)) - 1), '')
```

Comment: Hi, any idea how to achieve the attached